# Finding polynomials sattisfying $P\bigr(-c + K/(u+c)\bigl) (u+c)^2/K =P(u)$

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, functional-equations

Is there any simple way to find the polynomials satisfying the 
functional relation 
\begin{align*}
    P\left(-c + \frac{K}{u+c}\right) \frac{(u+c)^2}{K} = P(u) \tag{*}
\end{align*}
Where $K = (b+c)(a+c)$?

I have a hunch that one can restrain oneself into looking at polynomials of degree 2, else the left handside is not a polynomial. I tried inserting and assuming that 
$$
P(x) = A x^2 + B x + C
$$
When comparing coefficients I got something silly and strange. The problem rises when
trying to evaluate. 
$$
\int_a^b \frac{\log(x+c)}{P(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
If $P(x)$ satifies $(*)$ then, the integral can be rewritten into 
$$
\int_a^b \frac{\log K}{P(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Which is much easier to evalute. Alas finding such polynomials seems somewhat cumbersome. If $c=0$ then $P(x)=(x+b)(x+a)$ satifies the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

When $u$ tends to infinity then the modulus of the left side of the equality (*) grows not faster than a polynomial of degree 2. Therefore the polynomial from the right side of the equality has a degree at most two. Now, assuming that 
$P(x) = A x^2 + B x + C$ and comparing coefficients from both sides, we obtain a system

$$\begin{cases}
A=\frac 1K\left(Ac^2-Bc+C\right)\\
B=\frac {2c}K\left(Ac^2-Bc+C\right)-2Ac+B\\
C=\frac {c^2}K\left(Ac^2-Bc+C\right)+c(-2Ac+B)
\end{cases}
$$

Solving it, we obtain that $P(u)\equiv B(u+c)$ or a degenerated solution $K=0$ and $P(-c)=0$.